# Determining a formfield is selected

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have used the following code to find text and do a replace

```
Do
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Text = "QLD"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    If Selection.Find.Execute = False Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        Selection.Delete
        Selection.TypeText Text:="Queensland "
    End If
Loop
```

The client using this has started to use formfields now and wants the text format of the formfield to apply.

How can I determine that the selection contains a formfield to get the properties of it?

Answer (score 0):

To check if there is any `FormField` inside selection check this:

```
if Selection.FormFields.Count > 0 then
```

Assuming you have one `FormField` inside selection you could change any of its property like this (example of how to bold text):

```
Selection.FormFields(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
```

And to read current value of `FormField` use this:

```
Selection.FormFields(1).Result
```

Comment: When the selection is lager than the text contained in the field but dose not identify the text is in a form field when only the text is selected.

'Do
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Text = "QLD"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    If Selection.Find.Execute = False Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        If Selection.FormFields.Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox ("awesome")
        Else
        End If
    End If
Loop'